# How to insert a file to an Image datatype in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am trying to save a file to an Image datatype using inline query.

```
INSERT INTO tblPDFInfo(FileImage, PdfFileName, FeedDateTime, HasProcessed)
VALUES(@fileBytes, @fileName, getutcdate(), 0)
```

and then if I use `string.format` then it is rendering the byte array to string and so it serves no luck.

Another way if I create a sqlcommand and

```
   objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn, objTrans);
   objFileDataParam = new SqlParameter("@fileBytes", SqlDbType.Image);
   objFileDataParam.Value = (byte[])fileData;
   objCmd.Parameters.Add(objFileDataParam);

   objFileNameParam = new SqlParameter("@fileName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
   objFileNameParam.Value = PDFfileName;
   objCmd.Parameters.Add(objFileNameParam);
   objCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
```

Then when firing the query it is saying

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@fileBytes"

And if in inline query I am declaring the same variable then it too gives me error saying

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The variable name '@fileBytes'
>   has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a
>   query batch or stored procedure.

How could I correct this up to make it working. Well I am not bound to a specific datatype but I need to save the file and later on retrieve it too, I think the image datatype would be a good choice, but could not make it happen. Any suggestions would be really helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
string strSql="INSERT INTO tblPDFInfo (FileImage,PdfFileName,FeedDateTime,HasProcessed) 
               values(@fileBytes,@fileName,@getutcdate,@hasprocessed)";

byte []bytes=(byte[])fileData;
objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn, objTrans);
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@fileBytes", SqlDbType.Image,bytes.Length).Value=bytes;
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@fileName", SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value=PDFfileName;
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@getutcdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=DateTime.Now;
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@hasprocessed", SqlDbType.Bit).Value=0;

objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting -1 as the return incase of `ExecuteNonQuery` while in case of `ExecuteScalar` I am getting 0 as return.